# samba_dnsupdate dns_tkey_negotiategss: TKEY is unacceptable

Tags: domain-name-system, samba, bind

I'm trying to configurate dinamic update to bind

I have samba4.0.0rc5 running with bind 9.8 on Ubuntu 12.04.

by default the provision command dont create necesary dns.keytab. i've tested with the folloewing

```
# samba-tool domain exportkeytab /usr/local/samba/private/dns.keytab --realm=domain.com --principal DNS/ad.domain.com
```

but when i try the command `samba_dnsupdate` always i get `dns_tkey_negotiategss: TKEY is unacceptable`

the second method is create the dns.keytab file with [this guide](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-June/163123.html) but i get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Samba 4.1.9 + Ubuntu 14.04 (with BIND9_FLATFILE backend for DNS) but same issue here. The problem is access to the `private` directory of Samba (in my case `/var/lib/samba/private/`) and to the file `dns.keytab`.

My solution is:

```
chgrp bind /var/lib/samba/private/
chmod 750 /var/lib/samba/private/
chgrp bind /var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab
chmod 640 /var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab
```